# Flutter: How to check DataSnapshot is empty?

Tags: flutter

I am creating a `chat app` in Flutter. I want to add a `ProgressBar` when chat messages are loading from `Firebase`. For this I need to check is `DataSnapshot` empty. How to check that?

My Current Code:

```
           child: new FirebaseAnimatedList(
              query: reference,
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              reverse: true,
              sort: (a, b) => b.key.compareTo(a.key),
              //comparing timestamp of messages to check which one would appear first
              itemBuilder: (_, DataSnapshot messageSnapshot,
                  Animation<double> animation, int index) {
                return new ChatMessageListItem(
                  messageSnapshot: messageSnapshot,
                  animation: animation,
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: did you try messageSnapshot.hasData ?

Comment: hasData is not available. It's available in Firestore collection.

Comment: which package are you using to get FirebaseAnimatedList ?

Comment: import 'package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart';

Comment: looks like there is PR that was rejected  https://github.com/flutter/plugins/pull/256

Comment: any solution? Just I want to check is firebase reference has Data.

Comment: I found a solution what i need. Firebase animated list has arguemnt called "defult child". I added a progress bar there. but still my question is unsolved.

Comment: maybe you could use StreamBuilder with a ListView inside instead of FirebaseAnimatedList

Comment: detailed answer will be helpful for others @diegoveloper